# How to find differences between n arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, javascript-objects

I have an array called `props` that contains `n` number of arrays with objects and all arrays contain the same number of objects.

Each object has 4 properties : `participation_enabled`, `name`, `pathing_enabled`, `id` and these properties can have different values in the other arrays for the same property id...

My goal is to find all object properties that are different in the other arrays of objects and store them in another array called `diffs`.

Let's take the following example:

```
[
  [
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"PropEins", pathing_enabled:"true", id:"prop1"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"User Status", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop2"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Initial ID", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop3"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"User ID", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop4"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Subdomain", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop5"}
  ], 
  [
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"PropEins", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop1"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Room", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop2"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Phase", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop3"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Custom Insight 4", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop4"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Subdomain", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop5"}
  ], 
  [
    {participation_enabled:"true", name:"PropEins", pathing_enabled:"true", id:"prop1"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"true", name:"User Status", pathing_enabled:"true", id:"prop2"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"true", name:"Trackingcode", pathing_enabled:"true", id:"prop3"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"User ID", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop4"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Subdomain", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop5"}
  ]
]
```

For the above example the `diffs` array should contain the following objects:

```
[
  {id:"prop1", participation_enabled:["false","true"], pathing_enabled:["false","true"], index:0},
  {id:"prop2", participation_enabled:["false","true"], name:["User Status","Room"], participation_enabled:["false","true"], pathing_enabled:["false","true"], index:1},
  {id:"prop3", participation_enabled:["false","true"], name:["Initial ID","Phase","Trackingcode"], participation_enabled:["false","true"], pathing_enabled:["false","true"], index:2},
  {id:"prop4", name:["User ID","Custom Insight 4"], pathing_enabled:["false","true"], index:3}
]
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant way. But it works using underscore JS.

Hope this will helps you. Also add some error handling would be good idea.

**EDIT**
Add support to use google underscore methods. Now all should work.
https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/underscoregs#TOC-_values-Object-obj-

```js
var a = [
  [
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"PropEins", pathing_enabled:"true", id:"prop1"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"User Status", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop2"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Initial ID", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop3"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"User ID", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop4"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Subdomain", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop5"}
  ], 
  [
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"PropEins", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop1"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Room", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop2"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Phase", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop3"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Custom Insight 4", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop4"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Subdomain", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop5"}
  ], 
  [
    {participation_enabled:"true", name:"PropEins", pathing_enabled:"true", id:"prop1"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"true", name:"User Status", pathing_enabled:"true", id:"prop2"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"true", name:"Trackingcode", pathing_enabled:"true", id:"prop3"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"User ID", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop4"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Subdomain", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop5"}
  ]
];
var diff = {};
a.forEach(function(val, i){
  //first just init start object
  if (i == 0) {
    val.forEach(function(v1, ind){
      diff[v1.id] = {};
      diff[v1.id].index = [ind];
      for (var key in v1) {
        diff[v1.id][key] = [v1[key]];
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    //for all other values add them into array and remove dups
    val.forEach(function(v1){
      var id = v1.id;
      for (var key in v1) {
        diff[id][key].push(v1[key]);
      }
    });
  }
});

//now finalize data removing all that have only unique values
for (var key in diff) {
  var nested = diff[key];
  var index = nested.index.pop();
  for (nestedKey in nested) {
    nested[nestedKey] =  _.filter(nested[nestedKey], function(item, pos) {
      return nested[nestedKey].indexOf(item) == pos;
    });
    
    if (nested[nestedKey].length < 2) {delete nested[nestedKey];}
    
  }
  diff[key].id = key;
  diff[key].index = index
  if (_.keys(diff[key]).length < 3) {delete diff[key];}
}

diff = _.values(diff);

console.log(diff);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you know how can I include underscore JS in Google Script ?

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/underscoregs  maybe this way?

Comment: Hm..damn you dont have mapObject in google underscore script ((( let me this a bit

Comment: Add support for use of google underscore methods..Now all should work

Comment: Thank you, it works! I'll wait for user3297291 to edit his solution to determine which one is the best...

Comment: Can we do something to also add the index of the object in the response? Just like in my example

Comment: Sec i can try. Give me some time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122986/discussion-between-mykola-borysyuk-and-pavel-valeriu).

Comment: Add index. Try now.

Comment: Now index will be add and also empty values will be removed if no diffs were found.

Answer (score 0):

A pure js example. Note that if you can be sure all properties contain strings, you could replace the `indexOf` search with a object-property based approach to check for duplicates faster.

Important assumption:

- An object's index in the array determines matching objects

```js
var sampleData = [
  [
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"PropEins", pathing_enabled:"true", id:"prop1"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"User Status", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop2"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Initial ID", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop3"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"User ID", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop4"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Subdomain", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop5"}
  ], 
  [
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"PropEins", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop1"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Room", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop2"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Phase", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop3"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Custom Insight 4", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop4"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Subdomain", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop5"}
  ], 
  [
    {participation_enabled:"true", name:"PropEins", pathing_enabled:"true", id:"prop1"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"true", name:"User Status", pathing_enabled:"true", id:"prop2"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"true", name:"Trackingcode", pathing_enabled:"true", id:"prop3"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"User ID", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop4"}, 
    {participation_enabled:"false", name:"Subdomain", pathing_enabled:"false", id:"prop5"}
  ]
];

// Reduce an array of data arrays into one array of merged objects
function dataReducer (matches, current) {
  current.forEach(function(obj, i) {
    if (!matches[i]) {
      matches[i] = obj;
    } else {
      matches[i] = mergeObj(matches[i], obj);
    }
  });
  
  return matches;
};

// Merge two matching objects
function mergeObj(obj1, obj2) {
  Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(key) {
    if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
      obj1[key] = [].concat(obj1[key]);
      
      if (obj1[key].indexOf(obj2[key]) == -1) {
        obj1[key].push(obj2[key]);
      }
    }
  });
  
  return obj1;
};

var result = sampleData.reduce(dataReducer, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Google Script does not recognize `=>` ... it gives me a syntax error

Comment: Maybe can you please edit the code to ES5 (the "classic style") ?

Comment: I've replaced the arrow functions by regular ones. Should work in older versions of chrome now as well... ;)

Comment: if an object has no differences (like the last object) then it should only contain the `id` property

Comment: Oops, I missed that requirement. Sorry about that. I noticed I skipped the `index` prop as well. I don't have time to include them at the moment. Might edit this later. For now, I guess you'd have to go with the other answer or include those requirements yourself..

Comment: No problem! Thank you for providing me a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.
May be this is not most optimal way but it solves the problem.

```js
var mainArray = [
  [{
    participation_enabled: "false",
    name: "PropEins",
    pathing_enabled: "true",
    id: "prop1"
  }, {
    participation_enabled: "false",
    name: "User Status",
    pathing_enabled: "false",
    id: "prop2"
  }, {
    participation_enabled: "false",
    name: "Initial ID",
    pathing_enabled: "false",
    id: "prop3"
  }, {
    participation_enabled: "false",
    name: "User ID",
    pathing_enabled: "false",
    id: "prop4"
  }, {
    participation_enabled: "false",
    name: "Subdomain",
    pathing_enabled: "false",
    id: "prop5"
  }],
  [{
    participation_enabled: "false",
    name: "PropEins",
    pathing_enabled: "false",
    id: "prop1"
  }, {
    participation_enabled: "false",
    name: "Room",
    pathing_enabled: "false",
    id: "prop2"
  }, {
    participation_enabled: "false",
    name: "Phase",
    pathing_enabled: "false",
    id: "prop3"
  }, {
    participation_enabled: "false",
    name: "Custom Insight 4",
    pathing_enabled: "false",
    id: "prop4"
  }, {
    participation_enabled: "false",
    name: "Subdomain",
    pathing_enabled: "false",
    id: "prop5"
  }],
  [{
    participation_enabled: "true",
    name: "PropEins",
    pathing_enabled: "true",
    id: "prop1"
  }, {
    participation_enabled: "true",
    name: "User Status",
    pathing_enabled: "true",
    id: "prop2"
  }, {
    participation_enabled: "true",
    name: "Trackingcode",
    pathing_enabled: "true",
    id: "prop3"
  }, {
    participation_enabled: "false",
    name: "User ID",
    pathing_enabled: "false",
    id: "prop4"
  }, {
    participation_enabled: "false",
    name: "Subdomain",
    pathing_enabled: "false",
    id: "prop5"
  }]
];

var resultArray = mainArray[0];
for (var i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++) {
  var arrayTocheck = mainArray[i];
  for (var outer = 0; outer < resultArray.length; outer++) {
    row = resultArray[outer];
    if (i == 0) {
      row.participation_enabled = [];
      row.name = [];
      row.pathing_enabled = [];
    }
    for (var inner = 0; inner < resultArray.length; inner++) {
      var rowtoCheck = arrayTocheck[inner];
      if (row.id == rowtoCheck.id) {
        if (!row.participation_enabled.includes(rowtoCheck.participation_enabled) && rowtoCheck.participation_enabled != "") {

          row.participation_enabled.push(rowtoCheck.participation_enabled);
        }
        if (!row.name.includes(rowtoCheck.name) && rowtoCheck.name != "") {
          row.name.push(rowtoCheck.name);
        }
        if (!row.pathing_enabled.includes(rowtoCheck.pathing_enabled) && rowtoCheck.pathing_enabled != "") {
          row.pathing_enabled.push(rowtoCheck.pathing_enabled);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    resultArray[outer] = row;
  }


}
console.log(resultArray);
```